# Why does the entity's getter get called twice?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, getter

I use Spring Boot with Hibernate. I have an entity containing some credentials:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {

    @Column(name = "credentials", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> credentials;
}
```

On every read and save of the credentials I do use my custom 'encode(credentials)' and 'decode(credentials)' methods to only keep the encoded versions in my DB and use decoded everywhere else. This is how my getter looks like:

```
    public Map<String, Object> getCredentials() {
        Map<String, Object> encryptedCredentials = decode(this.credentials);
        return encryptedCredentials;
    }
```

But for some odd reason, it seems to be called twice, with one (the first) is an implicit call and the debugger does not stop there. Why do I think it is called twice? Because when the I debug it the value of
`this.credentials`
is already decoded. However, when I have the getter method like this:

```
    public Map<String, Object> getCredentials() {
        Map<String, Object> encryptedCredentials = this.credentials;
        return encryptedCredentials;
    }
```

the credentials I get during a debug are not decrypted, which imples that the getter gets called twice. Strange. What magic does the Hibernate do here and what best practices should I follow to avoid it?

Comment: If you stop it in the debugged, you can see in the IDE the stack of the calls that would lead you to the place where it was called and why.

Comment: Does method `decode` change the value of `this.credentials` internally?  Or just decodes and returns, keeping `this.credentials` as-is, i.e. encoded. Then there should not be any problem, even if it is called multiple times.  And yes, check the call-stack as @NikolasCharalambidis suggests to know from where does it get called in both the cases.

Comment: Have the method call (new RuntimeException()).printStackTrace() to log the stack to see what is calling your method as it would help determine why if a break point won't. There isn't enough info here to know who/what/why it might be called otherwise or even the API used that you see it occurring with. Best practice though might be to decode/encode it once, using onLoad and prePersist/PreUpdate events, and cache the results in the entity - but I don't see how your debugging proves the method is called twice. If the decode isn't in the Get call, it means the credentials were not encoded at all